# How many ways could up to n factors sum up to n

Tags: sequences-and-series

With `n = 2`, we only have 2 ways of adding integers to produce it:
`2` and `1 + 1`.

With `n = 3`, there are 3 possibilities:
`3`, `2 + 1`, and `1 + 1 + 1`.

Let's consider a last example, 5:
`5`,  `4 + 1`, `3 + 2`, `3 + 1 + 1`, `2 + 2 + 1`, `2 + 1 + 1 + 1`, and `1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1`

I have tried 10 on paper and counted 40 distinct ways integers between 0 to 10 could be summed up to 10. Is there a way to calculate the list size for any given number?

Comment: You're trying to calculate the number of [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: @Jack'swastedlife, I didn't expect this could be so complex. I thought there would be a formula to calculate the number of the partitions.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no formula but you can calculate number of partitions for bigger natural numbers if you study generating functions :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, these are integer partitions, which are notoriously hard to count. If you insist that order matters in your sum, i.e. $1+2$ is a different representation pf $3$ than $2+1$, then you enter the world of integer *compositions*, which play a bit nicer. Indeed there are $2^{n-1}$ ways of writing $n$ as a composition, and I'd recommend trying to find a proof for it; I find it very cool!